# Filtered Knowledge Article Search in Einstein bot

Tags: invocable-method, einstein-chatbot

I want to have a filtered search on the knowledge base using user's input in Einstein Bot. I understand there is an OOTB feature in Einstein bot to use Knowledge Object search wherein max of three matching articles can be returned. I want to only target a subset of knowledge base. The OOTB feature does not seem to provide any filter option.

As a workaround i was thinking of taking the article list returned by Object search and filter it using apex before displaying only the relevant articles to the user.

For some reason, I am unable to pass the list of articles to the backend. The input parameters slot does not show up in the apex action setup. If i make the input parameter required in the apex class, then only it shows up in the setup, but on running the bot it errors out saying the required input is missing.

[image]

Pseudo code below :

```
public class inputClass{
    @InvocableVariable(label='InputList' required=true)
    public list<Knowledge__kav> lstinpKAV;
}
public class outputClass{
    @InvocableVariable
    public list<Knowledge__Kav> lstoutKAV;
}
@InvocableMethod(label='Filter KAV')
public static List<outputClass> filterArticles(List<inputClass> inputParameters) {
    List<outputClass> outputParameters;
    try{
        if(!inputParameters.isEmpty()){
            system.debug('received input '+inputParameters[0]);
            //if the article is part of the applicable knowledge subset add to the return list else skip
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        
    }
    return outputParameters;
}
```

List of sobject is supported by invocableMethods but why is the connection not getting setup with bot.
How do i ensure that only a subset of knowledge base is used for the search

Comment: have you defined a corresponding variable of the appropriate type?